# CURL. Как отправить post запрос, состоящий из json и files

Tags: php, json, curl, fileupload

Подскажите, пожалуйста, необходимо отправить Post запрос, который состоит из json и нескольких файлов. Если отправлять только json, то проблем нет. Отправляю на api laravel. Основная задача скрипта - загрузить/обновить документы.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Сейчас этот код возвращает ошибку

> Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\MethodNotAllowedHttpException:  in file /var/www/trarchive-api-application/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/RouteCollection.php on line 255

Но если закомментировать

> curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_UPLOAD, true);

Будет ошибка валидации

> {"code":400,"message":{"files.0":["The files.0 must be a file."]}}

Файл существует, проверял функцией file_exists(), путь который передаю в CURLFile

Comment: Проверяй route. Измени на **any()** route в файле route/web.php

Comment: может мешает verbose или ssl?

Comment: @Jean-Claude, я пока локально пробую. "CURLOPT_VERBOSE" разницы особой нет

Answer (score 0):

Измени **route** (POST) на **any**

```
Route::any("SSILKA", 'YOUR METHOD');
```

Comment: Наверное, это не подойдёт, потому что есть такой URL, но только для route::get, который выводит все записи. Но я попробую

Answer (score 0):

Ничего не получилось через php-curl, поэтому пришлось прибегнуть curl через терминал.

```
curl POST 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/ead/eds/' --header 'Content-Type: multipart/form-data' --form 'files[]=@"/home/user/upload_file/1/1.pdf"' --form 'files[]=@"/home/user/upload_file/1/8.pdf"' --form 'data="{\"num\":\"1-00002\",\"reg_date\":\"2016-01-11\",\"name\":\"name document\",\"source_id\":2,\"ed_status_id\":4,\"files\":[{\"path\":\"\/home\/user\/upload_file\/1\/1.pdf\",\"file\":\"1.pdf\",\"fr_id\":1},{\"path\":\"\/home\/user\/upload_file\/1\/8.pdf\",\"file\":\"8.pdf\",\"fr_id\":2,\"parent_file\":\"1.pdf\"}]}";type=application/json'
```